# Auto calculation occurs on previous value

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a function that increments a number, takes the total and multiplies it by a price. However, when I click the button that increments for the first time it doesn't do anything. I click the button a second time and it works. However if I then click the button that decreases, then it does the previous function (e.g. adding) then pressing it a second time will decrease the value.

I understand that the `onClick="myFunction()"` may be in the wrong place, however I don't know where to put it. I want the total to be calculated automatically. A demo can be found at http://alpha.kentishtours.co.uk/destinations/bruges.php

The function that takes the value and multiplies it and calculates the total.

```
function myFunction()
{
    var a = document.getElementById('adult').value;
    z=39;
    x=a*z;
    var c = document.getElementById('child').value;
    if(a >= 1) {
        a=+30; }
    else {
        a=+39; }
    b=c;
    c=a*b
    d=x+c
    document.getElementById("total").innerHTML=d;
    document.getElementById("value").value = d;
    }`
```

These are the buttons that increment the number and call the function to calculate.

```
<div class="calculator">
<div class="calculator-submodule input-group">
<h4>Adult (12+)</h4>
<button class="btn theme-btn" id="decrease" value="Decrease Value" onClick="myFunction()" >-</button>
<input type="text" id="adult" value="1" class="form-control input-usmall" min="0"  disabled>
<button class="btn theme-btn" id="increase" value="Increase Value" onClick="myFunction()" >+</button>
</div>
<div class="calculator-submodule input-group">
<h4>Child (2-11)</h4>
<button class="btn theme-btn" id="decreasec" value="Decrease Value" onClick="myFunction()" >-</button>
<input type="text" id="child" value="0" class="form-control input-usmall"  min="0" disabled>
<button class="btn theme-btn" id="increasec" value="Increase Value" onClick="myFunction()" >+</button>
 </div>

 <div class="calculator-submodule">
 <span class="pound">£</span>
 <span id="total">39</span><span class="pound">.00</span>
 </div>
```

Comment: What is the logic of your function? I'm not sure what all it's doing. You might also try using onmouseup, and seeing if that solves it.

Comment: Maybe create all your variable at the top with the `var` keyword, to not pollute the global namespace. And then rename that to something more understandable. Also make sure, that you are dealing with numbers, and the right type of numbers. Having a `0.5` *adult* and `0.1` *child* can be problematic.

Comment: @David the idea of the function is for the user to select the quantity of tickets. They increment using the buttons which uses the increment file i have just added. This value is then multiplied by the price of the ticket which displays the total.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have functions in your increment.js script that change the value of the input after you get them in "myfuntion". You need to calculate the prices after the values are changed.

So first you should **remove** the lines below from this file:

http://alpha.kentishtours.co.uk/assets/scripts/increment.js

```
$("#increase").click(function(){
  var $n = $("#adult");
  $n.val(Number($n.val())+1);
}); 
$("#decrease").click(function(){
  var $n = $("#adult");
  $n.val(Number($n.val())-1);
}); 
$("#increasec").click(function(){
  var $n = $("#child");
  $n.val(Number($n.val())+1);
}); 
$("#decreasec").click(function(){
  var $n = $("#child");
  $n.val(Number($n.val())-1);
});
```

Also remove the `onClick="myFunction()"` attribute in your HTML form.

Then change all your myFunction script to this:

```
var adult = $('#adult'),
child = $('#child'),
total = $('#total'),
value = $('#value'),
increase = $('#increase'),
decrease = $('#decrease'),
increasec = $('#increasec'),
decreasec = $('#decreasec');

var calulate_price = function(a, c){   
  var p1 = 39,
      p2 = 30,
      PA = a * p1,
      PC, d;

  if(a >= 1) PC = c * p2;
  else PC = c * p1;

  d = PA + PC;

  total.text(d);
  value.val(d);
};

increase.click(function(){
  var a = Number(adult.val());
  var c = Number(child.val());  
  adult.val(++a);
  calulate_price(a, c);
}); 
decrease.click(function(){
  var a = Number(adult.val());
  var c = Number(child.val());  
  adult.val(--a);
  calulate_price(a, c);
}); 
increasec.click(function(){
  var a = Number(adult.val());
  var c = Number(child.val());  
  child.val(++c);
  calulate_price(a, c);
}); 
decreasec.click(function(){
  var a = Number(adult.val());
  var c = Number(child.val());  
  child.val(--c);
  calulate_price(a, c);
});
```

Everything working: http://jsbin.com/ohUniCa/2/edit?js,output

Comment: Hello, the price is calculated when a user presses one of the "+" or "-" buttons, using `onClick="myFunction"` It takes the value that is in the text boxes and multiplies them by the price of a ticket.

Comment: I did not understood this : ` if(a >= 1) {  a=+30; } ` . Is there a diferent price for children or it's more expensive for a single person? Plz explain how you are taxing ... then I can really help you.

Comment: yes, there are two prices for children. if they're with and adult they pay £30 but if they're on their own then they pay £39